# PHP redirect if the user has been authenticated or not

Tags: php, redirect

I'm new to php (1 and a half months in) and I have setup a PHP login script which checks with the database I've setup if they have registered or not and it works perfectly, but I would like to stop users from instead of logging in, typing in the URL in the address bar to access the page by typing http://example.com/home.html and if they do try to do this, checks if they have already signed in and if they haven't, redirects them to the login page to enter their credentials. Ive searched everywhere for one and they either don't help me at all or are to hard for a person new to PHP to understand. I believe it would include the use of php sessions but im not exactly sure how to code or write it

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a session:

```
if (!$_SESSION['is_logged_in']) {
   redirect_to_login_page();
}
```

then in your login script, after they successfully log in, you simply have

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
```

and any of your "protected" pages will allow them through.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your login script does something like:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = ...;
```

Then you can just do:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['userid'])) die(header("Location:/login.php"));
```

Of course, there are more elegant solutions, but they rely on more specific aspects of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some session check to start with and then include that file on top of all files which you have to protect. For example

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['authenticated']!=1)
{
echo "Not logged in";
}
```

And on login form action you could set that session value accordingly if username and password are correct